# Vertical float/overlap issue

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and want it to appear as a grid of boxes and rectangles.
I have a 6x6 grid of relatively-alined left-float divs. They work fine and fit neatly in a 900 width wrapper div. If i want a horizontal rectangle, i simply make one of these squares twice as wide (accounting for margins between, but that's irrelevant) and delete the one next to it. No problem.

The issue I have comes in when I want to make a rectangle twice as TALL. it ends up bumping everything left of it in the same row as it a line down. The same happens with a square twice as large (2x2 grid units).

Here's the code in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zucw9/
Essentially, how can I get either 8,9, and 10 to shift up one space, or for 6,7, and 8 to move into that gap, leaving 9 and 10 where 6 and 7 are right now?

Comment: Table? ... unless it is tabular data don't do it!.  wither use something like:http://960.gs/ or css3 grid layout http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/

Comment: I've been bred to stay away from tables until the day I die. haha I'll look at the css3 grid layout. I'm using HTML5 boilerplate, any suggestions as to ensuring that css3 stuff works on older browsers? I know there are a few options out there, but I was wondering if there's a personal favorite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/zucw9/10/

This solution isn't a very good solution but it works.

(I changed some of the names so i could read it better. (`.grid_rect_tall` became `.grid_tall` etc. `margin-left:10px; margin-right: 0px` etc.. became `margin: 5px;`)

basically you specify a -ve `margin-bottom` for the tall one and an extra margin so the other elements don't  overlap.

```
.grid_square, .grid_long, .grid_tall
{
    float: left;
    margin: 5px; 
    background: #6CC;
}

#main{
    position: relative;
    width: 905px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

.grid_square{
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
}

.grid_long{
    width: 290px;
    height: 140px;
}

.grid_tall{
    width: 140px;
    height: 290px;
    margin-bottom: -150px;  
}
.rbuffer
{
    margin-right: 155px;
}

.lbuffer
{
    margin-left: 155px;
}
```

I'd still go with my comment though and use either: http://960.gs or css3 grid layout: http://w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout

**EDIT:-** I thought i better put a why to my comment earlier that this is not a good solution. Simply put: if you want to change the layout of the page you will have to change the classes on the items as well as having to change the css.

Also created one with even more elements to show the possibilities: http://jsfiddle.net/zucw9/11/ (or in `em` instead of `px` because i was bored. http://jsfiddle.net/zucw9/15/)

Comment: This is actually a lot better than what I was messing around with (layered divs, even AP divs (shudder)). I'll try this out and play around with it, but this is best-answer material. haha

Answer (score 0):

The layout is standard, how it should be displayed. I would recommend to use another div which wraps up the dives that appear before the taller div. This is not a very flexible solution though.

Edit:  Move

```
    <div class="grid_square">8</div>
    <div class="grid_square">9</div>
    <div class="grid_square">10</div>
```

higher in hierarchy after

```
<div class="grid_square">2</div>
```

should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

i hope your thinking like below

code:

```
<div id="main">
        <div class="grid_square">1</div>
        <div class="grid_rect_long">2</div>
        <div class="grid_rect_tall">3</div>
        <div class="grid_square">4</div>
        <div class="grid_square">5</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div>
        <div class="grid_square">6</div>
        <div class="grid_square">7</div>
        <div class="grid_square">8</div>
        <div class="grid_square">9</div>
        <div class="grid_square">10</div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't think thats the idea the OP was looking for. You can achieve the same thing by using `display: inline-block` and a `<br />` tag